# Access GITHub repo via java API

Tags: java, github

**Problem**: I want to read files on a particular GITHub repository. With given condition i don't have to clone it.

**Explanation:** Connect to repository at given URL "https://github.my.company.corp/microsevice/first" with user name and password as given below - myuser and mypwd

**My research:** I understand that there are several Java API given at [this site](https://developer.github.com/libraries/).

But i could not get any way to connect with a particular repository and read the files.

Any sample will help me a lot on this.

Comment: There are several samples in the link you provided along with code - where are you having problems with them?

Answer (score 1):

I found this: https://github.com/eclipse/egit-github/tree/master/org.eclipse.egit.github.core. In README.md file have a explanation and sample code about how you can authenticate with your GitHub account. I hope that helps you